# Android Available Ram

Tags: android, ram

How much RAM is available for use by each app?

I read somewhere that each app could only use a max of 16 mb, but the total system memory is much higher.

Comment: The total RAM will be dependant on the device, different Android phones will have different amounts of RAM

Comment: You should have posted that as an answer.

Comment: I'm not actually looking for the total amount RAM available, I'm asking if there is a sandbox that restricts each app to only using a certain amount of RAM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each application is limited to 16MB of Java heap space, at least for devices with "normal" class screens. That limit has apparently been bumped to 24MB for devices with "large" class screens -- in part because of larger bitmaps such screens might manipulate, and probably in a trade-off for the minimum amount of device RAM such devices will need to have.